# extract index of element in list python

Tags: python

I have a list named 'partition'

```
[array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]), array([214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226,
       227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239,
       240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250]), array([251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263,
       264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276]), array([277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289,
       290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302,
       303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314]), array([30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46,
       47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63,
       64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]), array([ 71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,
        84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,
        97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,
       110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121]), array([122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134,
       135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147,
       148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160,
       161, 162, 163, 164]), array([165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177,
       178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190,
       191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203,
       204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213])]
```

And i try to extract the index of an element (1 for example) with this code:

```
a= partition.index(1)
```

But i get this error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_582922/1287398992.py in <module>
----> 1 a= partition.index(1)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can you help me please to fix this error?

Kind regards

Comment: arr? you mean partition?

Comment: the list is called 'partition'

Comment: @CozyCode no finally it does not work . no error but index is empty .. it should be 1

Comment: @CozyCode a new idea to help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

partition = array([array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]), array([214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226,
       227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239,
       240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250]), array([251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263,
       264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276]), array([277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289,
       290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302,
       303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314]), array([30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46,
       47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63,
       64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]), array([ 71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,
        84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,
        97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,
       110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121]), array([122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134,
       135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147,
       148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160,
       161, 162, 163, 164]), array([165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177,
       178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190,
       191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203,
       204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213])], dtype="object")

result = [(i, np.where(j == 1)[0]) for i, j in enumerate(partition) if np.any(np.where(j == 1))]
print(result)
```

The result will be in the format of (This is an example):

```
[(*the index of the array*, *an array with all indexes of the elements that are 1*), (*the index of the array*, *an array with all indexes of the elements that are 1*)]
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it though.

---

Or if you have a list of numpy arrays you could do something like this:

```
from numpy import array

partition = [array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]), array([214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226,
       227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239,
       240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250]), array([251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263,
       264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276]), array([277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289,
       290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302,
       303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314]), array([30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46,
       47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63,
       64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]), array([ 71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,
        84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,
        97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,
       110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121]), array([122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134,
       135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147,
       148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160,
       161, 162, 163, 164]), array([165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177,
       178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190,
       191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203,
       204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213])]

result = []

for i, j in enumerate(partition):
    for l in j:
        if l == 1:
            result.append((i, l))

print(result)
```